# How can I solve this system of equation analytically?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

$$
\begin{align}
i x'(t)= c A(t)(e^{-i q(t)}) y(t)
\end{align}
$$
\begin{align}
i y'(t)= c A(t)(e^{i q(t)}) x(t)
\end{align}
$$
when A(t) and q(t) are functions as follows:

\begin{align}
A(t)=a cos(wt-r),\\
q(t)=b+dt+k sin(wt+r)
\end{align}

where all of 
\begin{align}
a,b,c,d,k,w,r
\end{align}
are constants .

and the boundary condition is as follows:
$$
X(t=0)=1,\\
Y(t=0)=0 \\
$$
It might be possible to slightly simplify the solutions
by considering special cases. For example assume that
when one of the parameters of the theory, say $d$ has
some special values say $d_0=0$ or $1$ or something.
Then if in this case an analytical solution $x_0(t)$ and
$y_0(t)$ can be found, in the next step you may assume that
the solutions $x(t)=x_0(t)\cdot X(t)$ and $y(t)=y_0(t)\cdot Y(t)$.
Hopefully the equations for $X(t)$ and $Y(t)$ can be
much simpler??

Comment: I took the liberty of fixing your formatting

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get a closed-form solution in general, but with $d=0$ and $r=0$ Maple finds the following solution, where $s = \sqrt{4 a^2 c^2 + k^2 w^2}$:

$$ 
\eqalign{
x(t) &= \frac{s+kw}{2s} e^{-i (kw - s) \sin(w t)/(2w)} + \frac{s-kw}{2s} e^{-i(kw+s) \sin(wt)/(2w)} \cr
y(t) &=\frac{ac}{s} e^{ib} \left(e^{i(k w - s) \sin(w t)/(2w)} - e^{i(k w + s) \sin(w t)/(2w)}\right)}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert . But one more question: can we have a solution in the form below for example for x(t) :

#  x(t)= Xn e^(-inwt) 
where # shows the sigma notation and Xn are some coefficients . I need a solution in this form to approximate the Xn for n=1,2,3,4,5. Am I right? 

Comment: You may note that (if $w$ is real) the solution above is periodic with period $2\pi/w$, thus can be expanded in a Fourier series.  Your $X_n$ are coefficients of this series.  